# Elementary Os 6 Odin se me queda congelado siempre que inicio

Tags: odin

Buen día, hace poco he instalado el Elementary os 6, y hace unos dias cada vez que enciendo mi pc y abro algún  programa como por ejemplo Brave, la pc se queda congelada y no puedo hacer nada, el cursor del mouse y el sonido continúan normal, pero la imagen queda congelada, tengo que apagar mi laptop presionando 10 segundos el botón de encendido, porque no encuentro otra manera de arreglaro. 'Como puedo solucionarlo?

Mi laptop es una dell g5 5505, tiene 16 gb de ram y 100 gb de ssd para linux, el resto para windows. Por favor ayúdenme, ya arruiné un pendrive por tener que apagar a la fuerza mi pc.

Good morning, I recently installed the Elementary os 6, and a few days ago every time I turn on my pc and open a program such as Brave, the pc is frozen and I can not do anything, the mouse cursor and sound continue normal, but the image is frozen, I have to turn off my laptop by pressing 10 seconds the power button, because I can not find another way to fix it. How can I fix it?

My laptop is a dell g5 5505, it has 16 gb of ram and 100 gb of ssd for linux, the rest for windows. Please help me, I already ruined a flash drive by having to forcefully turn off my pc.

Comment: Is it every program that has this issue? Or is it 3rd-party applications? Do you see anything in `/var/log/syslog` that might point to an issue, such as crash notices or buffer overflows? 

Comment: Well, in the last few hours, I have noticed that it has only happened when I tried to open Brave or Chrome, when I open them, the screen freezes, then I reboot and it doesn't happen again. But if I turn off again, and enter after a few hours I again the same problem.

Comment: https://imgur.com/k4wwOXc This appears in the syslog at the time of crashing